# How to add synopsis/summary for a cmdlet in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Suppose you are writing some [PSCmdLet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in C#:

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Get a stack overflow exception.
/// </summary>
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Join, "StackOverflow")]
[OutputType(typeof(OverflowException))]
public class JoinStackOverflow : PSCmdlet {
  protected override void ProcessRecord() {
    throw new OverflowException("stack");
  }
}
```

If the module defining the above is loaded into PowerShell, the command `help Join-StackOverflow` will return the following:

```
NAME
  Join-StackOverflow

SYNTAX
  Join-StackOverflow  [<CommonParameters>]

ALIASES
  None

REMARKS
  None
```

How can I add a synopsis/summary for this cmdlet, e.g. the same as for `Get-Process`:

```
NAME
  Get-Process

SYNOPSIS
  Gets the processes that are running on the local computer or a remote computer.

...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cmdlet help is normally in the satellite XML file. Assuming the cmdlet is in the module *MyModule.dll*, the help file is normally in *MyModule\en-US\MyModule.dll-help.xml*

Help XML is so called MAML-format. In order to avoid composing it each time manually I created a tool (script library) [Helps](https://github.com/nightroman/Helps). It generates a template help script for a cmdlet which looks somewhat similar to help. Here is an [example](https://github.com/nightroman/Helps/wiki/Command-Help-Script). Then, after filling blanks ([example](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline/blob/master/Module/en-US/SplitPipeline.dll-Help.ps1)), another Helps command is called to convert this script into MAML XML.

P.S. There are other helper tools on the web. I tried a couple of them and decided to create my own.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic structure of the MyModule.dll-Help.xml file, which can be in the same directory as the module DLL itself, or in a culture subdirectory (such as en-US):

```
<!-- For a complete treatment of this format for PowerShell cmdlets, 
     see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525433.aspx -->
<command:command 
  xmlns:maml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10"
  xmlns:command="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10" 
  xmlns:dev="http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/2004/10">
  <command:details>
    <command:name>Verb-Noun</command:name>
    <command:verb></command:verb>
    <command:noun></command:noun>
    <maml:description><maml:para>Synopsis</maml:para></maml:description>
  </command:details>
  <maml:description><maml:para>Description</maml:para></maml:description>
  <command:syntax>
    <command:syntaxItem>
      <maml:name>Verb-Noun</maml:name>
      <command:parameter required="true" globbing="true" pipelineInput="true (ByValue)" position="1">
        <maml:name>ParameterName1</maml:name>
        <command:parameterValue required="true">string[]</command:parameterValue>
      </command:parameter>
      <command:parameter required="true" globbing="true" pipelineInput="true (ByPropertyName)">
        <maml:name>ParameterName2</maml:name>
        <command:parameterValue required="true">int32[]</command:parameterValue>
      </command:parameter>
      <!-- Additional parameter elements for each additional parameter. -->
    </command:syntaxItem>
    <!-- Additional syntaxItem elements for each additional parameter set. -->
  </command:syntax>
  <command:parameters>
    <command:parameter required="true" globbing="true" pipelineInput="true (ByValue)" position="1">
      <maml:name>ParameterName1</maml:name>
      <command:parameterValue required="true">string[]</command:parameterValue>
      <maml:description><maml:para>Parameter description</maml:para></maml:description>
      <dev:type>string[]</dev:type>
      <dev:defaultvalue>defaultvalue</dev:defaultvalue>
      <dev:possiblevalues>
        <dev:possiblevalue>
          <dev:value>value1</dev:value>
          <maml:description><maml:para>value description</maml:para></maml:description>
        </dev:possiblevalue>
        <dev:possiblevalue>
          <dev:value>value2</dev:value>
          <maml:description><maml:para>value description</maml:para></maml:description>
        </dev:possiblevalue>
      </dev:possiblevalues>
    </command:parameter>
    <command:parameter required="true" globbing="true" pipelineInput="true (ByPropertyName)">
      <maml:name>ParameterName2</maml:name>
      <maml:description><maml:para>Parameter description</maml:para></maml:description>
      <dev:type>int32[]</dev:type>
      <dev:defaultvalue>defaultvalue</dev:defaultvalue>
    </command:parameter>
    <!-- Additional parameter elements for each additional parameter. -->
  </command:parameters>
  <command:inputTypes>
    <command:inputType>
      <dev:type>
        <maml:name>System.String</maml:name>
        <maml:uri></maml:uri>
        <maml:description><maml:para></maml:para></maml:description>
      </dev:type>
      <maml:description><maml:para>You can pipe names …</maml:para></maml:description>
    </command:inputType>
    <!-- Additional inputType elements for each additional input type. -->
  </command:inputTypes>
  <command:returnValues>
    <command:returnValue>
      <dev:type>
        <maml:name>System.Object</maml:name>
        <maml:uri></maml:uri>
        <maml:description><maml:para></maml:para></maml:description>
      </dev:type>
      <maml:description><maml:para>When you …</maml:para></maml:description>
    </command:returnValue>
  </command:returnValues>
  <maml:alertSet>
    <maml:title>Note Title</maml:title>
    <maml:alert>
      <maml:para></maml:para>
    </maml:alert>
  </maml:alertSet>
  <command:examples>
    <command:example>
      <maml:title>----------  EXAMPLE 1  ----------</maml:title>
      <!-- The documentation (and SQLPS) suggests the PS C:\&gt; should go in the intro,
           but the dll-Help.xml files that come with PowerShell all seem to add it to the dev:code line. -->
      <maml:Introduction><maml:para>PS C:\&gt;</maml:para></maml:Introduction>
      <dev:code>Verb-Noun</dev:code>
      <dev:remarks>
        <maml:para> command description </maml:para>
        <!-- Two empty para elements signify the beginning of the output. -->
        <maml:para/>
        <maml:para/>
        <maml:para>output</maml:para>
      </dev:remarks>
    </command:example>
  </command:examples>
  <maml:relatedLinks>
    <maml:navigationLink><maml:linkText>Topic-name</maml:linkText><maml:uri></maml:uri></maml:navigationLink>
    <maml:navigationLink><maml:linkText>Topic-name</maml:linkText><maml:uri></maml:uri></maml:navigationLink>
  </maml:relatedLinks>
</command:command>
```

Comment: "Basic" ....... That's one of the most verbose and convoluted things I've ever seen.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's not an easy or approachable format. I thought a fill-in-the-blanks template or recipe would be helpful.

Comment: I know it's not you fault. It's Microsoft's. But, well... I didn't even realize it *was* a fill in the blank template. ;) It's not that your answer is bad. It's just the format is really difficult to even start wrapping your head around. "Basic" just didn't seem like a very fitting word. lol